# WebClient can't upload decimals

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to submit a decimal like 100.3 via WebClient but for some reason only 100 gets submitted.

```
private async Task addWeight(double newWeight)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(newWeight);
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

        var res = await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://..."), "&weightkg=" + newWeight);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: _doSearch");
    }
}
```

When I try to submit that decimal over other sources, such as curl, it works though.
The encoding is right.

Can someone see the issue here?

Comment: I would assume you need to urlencode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the value, since `.` has meaning in a URL.

Comment: Have you tried `newWeight.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`? Depending on the *culture* its string form can be `100.3` or `100,3`

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to inspect whether the request really is correct? Your code seems like a combination of request parameters ("&weightkg=") and POST (UploadStringAsync) to me.